# Retrofit 2 - how to extract POST arguments from Response / Call

Tags: java, rest, post, retrofit, retrofit2

1. I make a number of similar calls (with different values for `param1` and `param2`):

   ```
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("get_something") //param1=3&param2=400
   Call<SomeData> getSomeData(@Field("param1") int param1, @Field("param2") int param2);
   ```
2. In my callback I'd like to determine which call generated the response:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<SomeData> call, Response<SomeData> response) {
       // how to extract param1 and param2 here?
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you tried ``call.request().url().queryParameter("param1")`` or the other similar methods from https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html ?

Comment: Yes, nulls... Via debugger I see these parameters only as private fields, but I hoped that there was another way to obtain them.